# how to get google project id and pushwoosh app id?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

i am trying to push notification from phongap.

i followed following tutorial
http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android-gcm-push-notifications-guide/

but there i need to have **google project id** and **pushwoosh app id**.
so basically what is the process to get these ids..???

any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This guide shows where you can find your Google Project ID: http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/enabling-gcm-services-for-google-api/

Pushwoosh App ID is the Application Code (XXXXX-XXXXX) that you can find on your application page in Pushwoosh control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console and enable GCM there. You will see the project ID on the dashboard. (you can even see the project ID in the url once you logged in)